# MYSQL Total over time divided by instances overlapping

Tags: mysql, math

Not sure if this is possible and don't know how to approach this.   It is both a mathematical issue and query issue and wondering if this is possible with a MYSQL query.

If you think about a Gantt chart, I am looking to calculate the actual time (in seconds or minutes) spent on a by a person between two dates considering they could be also active on other tasks at the same time.  I am making the assumption that if they are working on say 2 tasks at the same time, that they are spending equal amount of time divided between them.  So if they work on two tasks for 20 minutes, then they actually spent 10 minutes on each task during the 20 minutes.

The chart below shows a pretend date start and end that is an 80 minute span.  The grey numbers show how much time would be spent on that task considering they are working on other tasks during the same time.

Does anyone have a solution to solve this with a MySQL query?
A result like:

- Person A  -- Task 1 -- Total: 6.667
- Person A  -- Task 2 -- Total: 33.334
- Person A  -- Task 3 -- Total: 26.667
- Person A  -- Task 4 -- Total: 13.334

[image: Table and Gantt Example]

Comment: Are the intervals fixed at 20 minutes or can they be of variable length?

Comment: no they could be any length.  I just did 20 intervals to make it easier to understand. :)